# creating a mongodb healthcheck (in dropwizard)

Tags: java, mongodb, dropwizard

Not necessarily specific to dropwizard, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to easily create a healthcheck for mongodb. This is in java, using version 3.3.0 of mongodb's own java driver.

I was hoping there would be a method that doesn't change the state of the database if it succeeds, but also throws an Exception when the query (or connection, or whatever) fails in order to return a health or unhealthy state. Ideally I'd perform a `find`, but this doesn't throw an Exception as far as I can tell.

Comment: What do you want to check with your healthcheck ?

Comment: Are you just wanting to perform a ping to the server? Or check if the Mongo process is running and the port is reachable?

Comment: I want to verify that we can connect and perform queries, so ensure it's reachable and that we're authenticated to work with it - basically ensure that what my application depends on is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just list all collections in database like:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(addr, opts);
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(database);
try {
    MongoIterable<String> allCollections = db.listCollectionNames();
    for (String collection : allCollections) {
        System.out.println("MongoDB collection: " + collection);
    }
} catch (Exception me) {
    // problems with mongodb
}
```

Comment: `getDb` is deprecated in the version I'm using, and `mongoClient.getDatabase("database").listCollectionNames();` doesn't seem to throw any exceptions.

Comment: Well, please use your way of opening database connection. And MongoException is runtime so it's not required to catch it: http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.3/com/mongodb/MongoException.html

Comment: I just tested this code after killing my mongodb process, no exception was thrown: 
  @Override
  protected Result check() {
    try {
      mongoClient.getDatabase("database").listCollectionNames();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("mongo db down: {}", e.getMessage());
      return Result.unhealthy("Couldn't list collections");
    }
    return Result.healthy();
  }

i tried catching "MongoException" and "RuntimeException" as well, no go.

Comment: Maybe we should go though list... I added print statements in the answer. If you print them after you disconnect what do you see?

Comment: strange. iterating over the actual entries seems to make all the difference. i just went over these scenarios: https://gist.github.com/jayceekay/59f61e875fd658519dede2255605cce9.
your answer gives me the desired effect for the most part though, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126980/discussion-between-justin-and-rsutormin).